# JSONPath : How to filter nested array?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a json like below:

```
[
    {
        "skuId": "1234",
        "plans": [
            {
                "plan": {
                    "planName": "plan1",
                    "planId": "abcd1231",
                }
            },
            {
                "plan": {
                    "planName": "plan2",
                    "planId": "loks3123",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "skuId": "5341",
        "plans": [
            {
                "plan": {
                    "planName": "plan3",
                    "planId": "awer3234",
                }
            },
            {
                "plan": {
                    "planName": "plan4",
                    "planId": "gefd4231",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "skuId": "7649",
        "plans": [
            {
                "plan": {
                    "planName": "plan5",
                    "planId": "kitv5397",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now i have a `planId "loks3123"`, and i want to get the `skuId` where it belongs to. In this case `planId "loks3123"` belongs to `skuId "1234"`.
Is it possible using JsonPath to do that? If so, How to do that using JsonPath? If not, what should i do?
Thanks！

Comment: Also I found this: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) you can use [filter operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) `in`

```
$..[?('loks3123' in @.plans[*].plan.planId)].skuId
```

Try here : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

---

If you are using [Newtonsoft.json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

```
$..[?(@.plans[*].plan.planId == 'loks3123')].skuId
```

Try here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/6n4vAd

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.json, so this seems not work.

Comment: @peterChar if you are using  newtonsoft  the marked answer shouldn't work either.

Comment: @peterChar Check the fiddle using newtonsoft.json

Comment: I do use Jayway JSONPath and your answer seems so much easier to understand than mine.  I learned something today. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Akshay G That works, Thank you! And sorry for my lately accept.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find a node containing a plans attribute that contains a planId attribute that matches your text. Using the suggestion at the end of https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287 you can get what you want with:

`$..[?(@.plans[?(@.plan.planId == 'abcd1231')] empty false)].skuId`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation for your problem using javascript and in the solution 'data' is your json data

```
    let findstring="loks3123";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        let sku=data[i];
        for(var j=0;j<sku.plans.length;j++){
            let plans=sku.plans[j];
            if(plans.plan.planId==findstring){
                console.log("skuId:"+sku.skuId);
            }
        }
    }
```