# Are Nested filters supported by Newtonsoft in jsonpath expressions?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I looked at [another qs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72724938/6468247). But the ans does not work with newtonsoft 13.0.3.

I have posted my qs on [github](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287#issuecomment-1668068318).

Basically in a json like

```json
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "authors": [
                    {
                        "firstName": "Nigel",
                        "lastName": "Rees"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Evelyn",
                        "lastName": "Waugh"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "authors": [
                    {
                        "firstName": "Herman",
                        "lastName": "Melville"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Somebody",
                        "lastName": "Else"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "authors": [
                    {
                        "firstName": "Evelyn",
                        "lastName": "Waugh"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Nigel",
                        "lastName": "Rees"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "authors": [
                    {
                        "firstName": "J. R. R.",
                        "lastName": "Tolkien"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I would like to get the jsonpath filter expression that would allow me select title of the book with an author whose last name is Waugh.
I am using Newtonsoft 13.0.3 with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested queries are supported by [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) but the `empty false` syntax from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72724938/6468247) is not.  Instead use the `?(<boolean expr>)` syntax as shown in the [original JSONPath proposal](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to select array members that have matching properties like so:

```
var titles = jtokenRoot
    .SelectTokens("store.book[?(@.authors[?(@.lastName == 'Waugh')])].title")
    .ToList();
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QAStFx).

Notes:

- `authors[?(@.lastName == 'Waugh')]` selects any author that has a `lastName` of `Waugh`.
- `store.book[?(@.authors[?(@.lastName == 'Waugh')])]` selects any book that has any author that has a `lastName` of `Waugh`.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139304/3744182) to *[SelectTokens with specific c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76139164/3744182)* for another example of a nested query.
- The [original JSONPath proposal](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) states that `()` should be a ***script expression, using the underlying script engine*** -- but does not specify any requirements for that "underlying script engine" in any way, which clearly leaves some room for interpretation as to what queries should and should not be supported.  Thus, while most JSONPath query engines support the simple examples shown in the proposal, they all seem to differ on what is supported beyond that.

  Newtonsoft has its own query engine, the code for which can be found [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath).
- For more complicated string matching, you can use Newtonsoft's [regex operator](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/RegexQuery.htm) `=~`.  For instance, the following query strips leading and trailing whitespace and ignores case:

  ```
  SelectTokens("store.book[?(@.authors[?(@.lastName =~ /^(?i)[\\s]*waugh[\\s]*$/)])].title")
  ```

  Hat tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583715/3744182) by [stevemegson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25028/stevemegson) to *[C# RegEx: Ignore case... in pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1583678/3744182)* for the `(?i)` syntax.

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J4Bwdi).

Comment: It works.
In my code I was using SelectToken instead of SelectTokens which would not work as well.
Thank you.